# How to add min, max values in summary report csv for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am creating summary report in Jmeter and storing it in csv file. But when I check the csv file, I do not get the min max values in it as seen in the summary GUI. How can I get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Summary Report listeners shows the aggregate results (`group by label`). So we can calculate min, max and avg etc. But when you configure it to write the results in csv format, it logs the each sampler result details. So you can not see the min, max details. But you can import the csv in the summary report listener to see them again. It is applicable for all the listeners.

For ex: You can not expect a graph listener to create graph while storing it in jtl/csv file!

Comment: As I have to add the values to database through csv file., I want them in the csv file. Isn't there any way to get them in the csv file ?